# Connect pinned map marker to user ID in android

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication, google-maps-markers

In an app I am making I wanted to enable a single user to post only 5 markers. I did this, but I think this will disable user to pin a marker when someone else pinned 5.

My question is how to connect marker to users unique ID so that he can still pin markers after others pinned more than 5.

Code I used for disabling more than 5 markers is:

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Marker marker; // Marker
    int markerCount = 0; // Marker counter

   //Add marker on long click
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    int iMax = 5; // Max number of markers

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        if (markerCount < iMax) {
            // start SendMessageActivity need to add marker to message activity
            startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SendMessageActivity.class));

            markerCount = markerCount + 1;
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker))
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                    arg0.longitude))
                    .visible(true));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only " + iMax + " markers allowed at the same time",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you assuming one user per device?  I don't see how this code would affect other users on another device.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. That is right - 5 markers per device. I am trying to make a map app that would allow users to share locations with other users and all the markers would be added to the map. I still haven't started with aws, so I haven't tested it with other users. I'm a beginner so I was not really sure this code would would affect other devices. Thanks again :)